# Does Serialization degrade Spark performance?

Tags: apache-spark

Given the following case class:

```
case class User(name:String, age:Int)
```

An `RDD` is created from a `List` of instances of Users

The following code filters the RDD to remove users above the age of 50

```
trait Process {
  def test {
    val rdd = ... // create RDD
    rdd.filter(_.age>50)
  }
}
```

In order to add logging, a separate validate function is created and passed to the filter, as follows:

```
trait Process {
  def validate(user:User) {
    if (user.age>50) {
      true
    }
    else {
      println("FAILED VALIDATION")
      false
    }
  }

  def test {
    val rdd = ... // create RDD
    rdd.filter(validate)
  }
}
```

The  following exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

The code works by making the class in which the validate function is defined serializable:

```
trait Process extends Serializable
```

Is this the correct way to handle the `Task not serializable` exception, or is there a performance degradation to using serialization within Spark? Are there any better ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a performance degradation to using serialization within Spark

*Task* serialization (as opposed to *data* serialization, that occurs when shuffling / collecting data) is rarely noticeable performance-wise, as long as the serialized objects are small. Task serialization occurs once per task (regardless of the amount of data processed).

In this case (serializing the `Process` instance), the performance impact would probably be negligible since it's a small object.

**The risk** with this assumption ("`Process` is small, so it's OK") is that over time, `Process` might change: it would be easy for developers not to notice that this class gets serialized, so they might add members that would make this slower.

> Are there any better ways to do this

You can avoid serialization completely by using static methods - methods of `objects` instead of classes. In this case, you can create a *companion object* for `Process`:

```
import Process._

trait Process {
  def test {
    val rdd = ... // create RDD
    rdd.filter(validate)
  }
}

object Process {
  def validate(user:User) {
    if (user.age>50) {
      true
    } else {
      println("FAILED VALIDATION")
    false
    }
  }
```

Objects are "static", so Spark can use them without serialization.

Comment: Tzach, thanks. For defining the workflow and the functions which comprise it, is it better to avoid classes completely and only use Objects?

Comment: I think it's a rather common practice - using either _anonymous_ functions or an object's function as RDD transformations.